Camera open triggers overlay to open on Expo App in React Native project with WebView
I'm developing an app that uses machinelearning to detect yogaposes for a school project. I'm not experiences enough to work in React Native with the camera and my model and so on, so I made the functionality in a basic html page that's online and I use WebView to show it in my app. I'm testing on iOS, in Expo.
What happens is this: the screen opens, it loads the html page, it asks for my camera, I say yes, it opens the camera as it should but then an overlay opens like it's showing a live feed or a fullscreen video. When I swipe it away, I can see the camera working behind it, but once I click the X to close it, my camera also stops.
Weird question, I know, but does anyone have an idea about how to fix this?
HTML code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Yogism Tech Demo</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="./src/media/logo.svg" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
</head>

<body onload="init()">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="label-container" class="label-container"></div>
        <div id="webcam-container" class="webcam-container"></div>
        <div class="record-button-container">
            <button type="button" class="record-button"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@teachablemachine/image@latest/dist/teachablemachine-image.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const URL = "src/imageModel/";

        let model, webcam, labelContainer, maxPredictions;

        async function init() {
            const modelURL = URL + "model.json";
            const metadataURL = URL + "metadata.json";
            model = await tmImage.load(modelURL, metadataURL);
            maxPredictions = model.getTotalClasses();

            const flip = true;
            const webcamWidth = window.innerWidth;
            const webcamHeight = window.innerHeight;
            webcam = new tmImage.Webcam(webcamWidth, webcamHeight, flip);
            await webcam.setup();
            await webcam.play();
            window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

            document.getElementById("webcam-container").appendChild(webcam.canvas);
            labelContainer = document.getElementById("label-container");
            for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) {
                labelContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
            }
        }

        let lastPredictionTime = 0;

        async function loop() {
            const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
            if (currentTime - lastPredictionTime >= 2000) {
                await predict();
                lastPredictionTime = currentTime;
            }
            webcam.update();
            window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        }

        async function predict() {
            const prediction = await model.predict(webcam.canvas);
            let maxProbability = 0;
            let maxIndex = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) {
                if (prediction[i].probability > maxProbability) {
                    maxProbability = prediction[i].probability;
                    maxIndex = i;
                }
            }
            const className = prediction[maxIndex].className;
            const probability = prediction[maxIndex].probability.toFixed(2);

            labelContainer.innerHTML = className;

            labelContainer.style.backgroundColor = "";
            labelContainer.style.color = "#F5F5F5";
            labelContainer.style.fontFamily = "Archivo";
            labelContainer.style.opacity = "1";
            labelContainer.style.border = "2px solid transparent";
            labelContainer.style.borderRadius = "15px";

            switch (className) {
                case "Not doing pose":
                    labelContainer.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(165, 157, 154, 0.65)"; // 65% transparent grey
                    labelContainer.style.borderColor = "#A59D9A"; // Grey border color
                    break;
                case "Fair":
                    labelContainer.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 248, 91, 0.65)"; // 65% transparent yellow
                    labelContainer.style.borderColor = "#FFF85B"; // Yellow border color
                    break;
                case "Decent":
                    labelContainer.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(250, 228, 203, 0.65)"; // 65% transparent orange
                    labelContainer.style.borderColor = "#FAE4CB"; // Orange border color
                    break;
                case "Excellent":
                    labelContainer.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(61, 255, 92, 0.65)"; // 65% transparent green
                    labelContainer.style.borderColor = "#3DFF5C"; // Green border color
                    break;
                case "Perfect":
                    labelContainer.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(61, 255, 243, 0.65)"; // 65% transparent blue
                    labelContainer.style.borderColor = "#3DFFF3"; // Blue border color
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    // const runFirst = ;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <WebView
          source={{
            uri: "https://yogism-demo-formcheck.vercel.app/",
          }}
          onMessage={(event) => {}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

Picture 1: opening the app

Picture 2: the overlay opens automatically and gives a black screen

Picture 3: what is behind the overlay (I can see my head moving so the camera works, but if I close the overlay, it freezes)


i would highly suggest using Expo-Camera (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/).
